# Perforce making read only

Tags: perforce

I need to make the repositories inside a depot as read-only, so that no one should check in any files. 
Could any one assist on the same or provide some commands to make a specific repo read only. 
Any help would be appreciated. 
Let me know, if any information is needed, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Run `p4 protect`.  Change:

```
super user you * //...
write user * * //...
```

to:

```
super user you * //...
read user * * //...
```

Now the entire repository is read-only to everyone except you.  You can add additional lines as needed to make specific parts writable.  See `p4 help protect` for more information.

Comment: Could you please help me with an example. That would be great.

Comment: If suppose I have a repo //test/project1

Comment: Then instead of `//...` in Sam's answer, use `//test/project1/...`